# Swift Can I begin new section in the end of previous section of UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've incorporated index scrolling for collectionView in my test app and it needs sections to work properly. The default behavior of collection view is to leave blank space at the end of section if last row has less items than usually. Is there a way to begin new section, let's say section 5 in the place of last item of section 4?

[image: Desired look]